# Prove that $\sin(\tan 1)>\tan(\sin 1)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\sin(\tan 1)>\tan(\sin 1)$?
All given measurements are in radians. I have tried comparing the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ but I wasn't able to proceed with it.

Comment: I think I've seen this somewhere, it's an old problem from some school competition. But you have a mistake, the sign $>$ is in the other direction $<$

Answer (score 3):

We may start from the fact that $\log\cos x$ is concave on $I=[0,1]$ and over there
$$ \tan(x)+2\sin(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\cos^2 t}+\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t)\,dt+\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t)\,dt\geq x $$
holds by Holder inequality. This leads to
$$ \cos^3(x) \geq \cos(\tan x)\cos^2(\sin x) $$
and by rearranging
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\tan(\sin x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(\sin x)}\geq\frac{\cos(\tan x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\tan x). $$
By integrating the middle terms on $[0,1]$ we get that $\tan(\sin 1)\color{red}{\geq} \sin(\tan 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin(\theta)\le1=\tan\dfrac\pi4$, it suffices to prove

$$\sin1>\frac\pi4.$$
By Taylor, as we have an alternating series,

$$\sin 1>1-\frac16.$$